# Loading all kmz files to google maps api

Tags: google-maps, kml

I need to load layers in a map. I have a compressed layer in +4 parts (layer1part1.kmz, layer1part2.kmz, layer1part3.kmz and so ) these are parts of one huge KML file. Is it possible to load more than one kmz file to the google map via google api?

What I need is to load the whole layer, but as there are size limits I have them in separate parts.
I've searched google api docs but it always loads one file.

Im using loadKmlLayer function

```
function loadKmlLayer(src, map) {
    var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(src, {
      suppressInfoWindows: true,
      preserveViewport: false,
      map: map
    });
   }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps API Multiple KML Layers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34464021/google-maps-api-multiple-kml-layers) (KmlLayer displays KMZ files)

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to load different layers using a layer array and then the function loadKmlLayer.

```
var layers = [];
  layers [0] = new google.maps.KmlLayer("http://layer1part1.kmz",{
    preserveViewport: false,
    map: map
  });

  layers [1] = new google.maps.KmlLayer("http://layer1part2.kmz",{
    preserveViewport: false,
    map: map
  });
```

However this solution still has the limit per layer and it's not very handy when you have many many layers ( say more than 10, due to a large kml file ).